# How to command app to do certain function by sending sms to the mobile in which app is installed?

Tags: android

Just like Button press(onClickListener) I want to perform certain task by sending sms to the device in which app is installed.

Comment: can you be more specific and clear?

Comment: Refer this https://mobiforge.com/design-development/sms-messaging-android

Answer (score 2):

Write SMSReceiver class and from that class call the method of button pressed.

**SMSReceiver**

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction()
                .equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {
                Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdusObj.length];
                String body = null;
                // getting SMS information from Pdu.
                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                    messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                }
                for (SmsMessage currentMessage : messages) {
                    // body has the actual message
                    body = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                    if(body.equals("your message")) {
                        yourMethod(); //This method should be the same method called from Button press(onClickListener)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And add this to manifest.xml before `</application>` tag:

```
 <receiver android:name="SMSReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```